# Android Assets - Unable to access

Tags: android, assets

Using this code it should return a list of the assets. But it crashes, with a "Source not found, Edit Source Lookup Path..." message in the debugger when I call the list method:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    AssetManager assets = this.getAssets();
    try { 
         //error happens on this next line
        String[] l = assets.list(null);
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
String[] arr = getAssets().list("");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try passing a path to `AssetManager#list(String)` instead of `null`.